# Setting up Git, Jira, Jenkins and uderstanding the workflow

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jira

I do not have any professional experience in project management and in my work I have never met a complete development workflow. So I try to understand it theoretically. For a person like me it is clear how Jira, Git and Jenkins work separately and what is a purpose of each of them, however it is not clear at all how they work together and in which order they have to be set up.

Ideally I get a Jira ticket, the Git branch is created for implementing this feature (bug etc.), when somebody commits to develop branch - Jenkins rebuilds a develop and updates tickets with results of builds and tests and it assures that in every moment of time the develop is as integrated as possible decreasing the amount of reintegration work for an individual developer.

So the question is: In which order we set them up and integrate these three things?

Comment: I ❤ this question but it is too broad for stack overflow. Research continuous integration and potentially https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Git first.

Jenkins will use a Git repo URL in order to checkout the sources from said repo and execute build steps on those sources.

Finally Jira can be setup last, and Jenkins can use the [JENKINS JIRA Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) to update Jira ticket status from a build.
See also "[Jenkins Pipeline + Jira](https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/)".